# Google Play Console Once the pre-registration exprires, what are some steps to follow to launch the app in stores?

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-games

it's my first time with pre-registration in Google Play.
I was wondering what I need to do once the pre-registration date is over - will Google play release the app automatically with the current build, or do i need to take additional actions?

Step-by-step explanation would be extremely helpful! Thank you in advance.

I did take a look in Google Play Console help, chatted with the service, but the only response I got was just the guideline.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store questions are off-topic. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool. For more information, see the [help/on-topic]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.